# EF 4 Query - Issue with Multiple Parameters

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

A trick to avoiding filtering by nullable parameters in SQL was something like the following:

```
select * from customers where (@CustomerName is null or CustomerName = @CustomerName)
```

This worked well for me in LINQ to SQL:

```
string customerName = "XYZ";
var results =
   (from c in ctx.Customers 
    where (customerName == null || (customerName != null && c.CustomerName == customerName)) 
    select c);
```

But that above query, when in ADO.NET EF, doesn't work for me; it should filter by customer name because it exists, but it doesn't.  Instead, it's querying all the customer records.  Now, this is a simplified example, because I have many fields that I'm utilizing this kind of logic with.  But it never actually filters, queries all the records, and causes a timeout exception.  But the wierd thing is another query does something similarly, with no issues.

Any ideas why?  Seems like a bug to me, or is there a workaround for this?  I've since switched to extension methods which works.

Thanks.

Comment: This query is fine (if redundant!), as written. Try it in LINQPad. Your problem is in the code you *didn't* put in the question.

Comment: Redundant yes; actually though, with LINQ to SQL,  there were times where if I didn't have a redundant not null check with a nullable type, it would error, and when I put it in, it would work fine.  Probably not as much of an issue with a string, but I got in a habit just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still didn't figure it out, but rewriting it as a proc fixed the issue, so that was my workaround, as bad as that is.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it with a ternary operator in the `where` clause?

```
where (customerName == null ? true : c.CustomerName == customerName)
```

Comment: No, I will try that out.  Thanks.

Comment: This did not resolve the issue.  Unfortunately, it's still ignoring the query conditions.