# Entity Framework: search for database entries with null columns

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, code-first

I have the following model:

```
public class FactCache
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime MonthDate { get; set; }
    public string AttributeKey { get; set; }

    public decimal RawValue { get; set; }
    public decimal ManDayValue { get; set; }
    public decimal FTEValue { get; set; }

    public int? InputResourceID { get; set; }
    public int? PhaseID { get; set; }

    public virtual InputResources InputResource { get; set; }
    public virtual DimPhase Phase { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see above, `InputResourceID` and `PhaseID` are nullable optional fields.

I want to write a query to find the first entry for a given date and `AttributeKey` where both `PhaseID` and `InputResourceID` are null.

I have tried the following code:

```
FactCache fact = db.FactCache.FirstOrDefault(
  a => a.InputResourceID == null
  && a.PhaseID == null
  && a.MonthDate == monthDate
  && a.AttributeKey == key);
```

However, it returns a null object. What is the correct way to write the above query?

I have checked the database and there are indeed entries with null `PhaseID` and `InputResourceID`.

Comment: Have a look at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682429/how-can-i-query-for-null-values-in-entity-framework), which version of EF are you using?

Comment: Forgive the obvious question: does it still return null if you remove the `MonthDate` and `AttributeKey` checks?

Comment: @SteveWilkes: Yes the problem persists

Comment: I have fond something strange in the database (I am using code first): Appart from the `InputResourceID` column, code first has added a second `InputResources_ID` column. It seams convention over configuration has not worked (I added `public virtual ICollection<FactCache> FactCache { get; set; }` to the `InputResources` model) No idea if this has any relation

Comment: @Andomar: I am using version 4. The link you provided uses a different notation to what I am use to, does that meen that the notation above cannot handle null values?

Comment: After reading the post suggested by @Andomar and this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16309866/call-is-failing-with-null-parameter) I think I am going to try to upgrade the project to EF6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, but perhaps...

```
FactCache fact = db.FactCache.FirstOrDefault(
  a => false == a.InputResourceID.HasValue
  && false == a.PhaseID.HasValue
  && a.MonthDate == monthDate
  && a.AttributeKey == key);
```

Comment: Yep, seems to work. Still wish I could use native C# `null`, but it looks like I'll have to wait until my team decides we can upgrade to EF5. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just a note, I you are lucky enough to be running EF version 5 or above try the solution proposed here: [Call is failing with null parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16309866/call-is-failing-with-null-parameter)